# Android application with syncadapter using REST client server communication and google oauth

Tags: android, rest, oauth

I am planning to develope an android app, that syncs its data with a server over a syncadapter using a REST architecture. The question is, is it possible to use the google account to authenticate the user at the server? If it **is** possible, how? Do you have any code snippets for me?

-
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this example by google:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

And take a look at these docs
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is there a "simple" way to download all the source code or do i have to dig through the directories by myself?

Comment: Ah, well I figured it out. The samples are downloadable using the sdk manager. Thanks so far! I ll let u know if it works out :D

Comment: Yup they should also be in your sdk folder under samples. Good luck!